# Normalization of a table

Tags: database-design, normalization, relations

I am trying to normalize the following table but having some difficulties

```
Mem_id mem_name phone email Book_num Book_titl Author_nam publication edition
100     smith    12443 eml1    200     physics   john         MACGROW   1ST
100     smith    12443 eml1    201     math      martin,tina  MACGROW   2ND
101     hena     1020  eml2    200     physics   john         MACGROW   2ND 
102     moon     2020  eml3    204     new java  korth,chira  ALPHA     4TH
```

1NF:

Member:

```
Mem_id mem_name phone email 

100     smith    12443 eml1 

101     hena     1020  eml2    

102     moon     2020  eml3
```

Book:

```
Mem_id Book_num  Book_titl  Author_name  publication edition

100     200       physics      john        MACGROW      1ST

100     201       math       martin,tina   MACGROW      2ND

101     200       physics      john        MACGROW      2ND

102     204       new java   korth,chira   ALPHA        4TH
```

2NF:

Member:

```
Mem_id mem_name phone email 

100     smith    12443 eml1 

101     hena     1020  eml2    

102     moon     2020  eml3
```

Issue:

```
Mem_id Book_num  

100     200       

100     201       

101     200       

102     204
```

Book:

```
Book_num  Book_titl  Author_name  publication edition

200       physics      john        MACGROW      1ST

201       math       martin,tina   MACGROW      2ND

204       new java   korth,chira   ALPHA        4TH
```

Now i am having difficulty here.Am i on the right way to the normalization ?Is it possible to normalize the book table to 3NF OR it is already in 3NF ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could go a little further and take the Author out and having a new table named Authors and you could be more rigid and take publication as well.

Book:

```
Book_num  Book_titl  Author_id  publication edition

200       physics      1        MACGROW      1ST

201       math         2        MACGROW      2ND

204       new java     3        ALPHA        4TH
```

---

Author:

```
Author_id Author_name

   1      john

   2      martin,tina

   3      korth,chira
```

Still, remember that going full onto normalization has drawbacks on performance as well.

It all depends on the business and how you are trying to manage the data.

Comment: So what do you think is it better to stop on 2NF for the above case ?

Comment: It all depends on the business, if you are making a database with this configuration I assume there  are much more tables involved. If performance is the key and the workload is high, then going on step more and  taking Author and Publication out and making codes for them would be really great. Otherwise, if this is a sample database or there is very low workload you won't need it since you will make effort to separate them as new records arrive rather than keeping it simple and fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize, like most databases, to 3nf or bcnf and reach the maximum useful level. So go for it.

The purpose of normalization is to maintain data integrity -- to make it impossible at best, extremely difficult at worst, for bad data to work their way into your database as the data is manipulated during the course of its use.

Sure, cutting back on the normalization may make the application(s) a little more responsive. But try telling your users, "The answers may contain a few errors but I can get it to you 30 msecs faster." See if they're OK with that.

There's a very good chance you will never run across a significant performance issue that can only be solved by denormalizing. Until you do, normalize "all the way down."

You can also create a wall of abstraction between the application layer and the data layer by using views. In fact, don't even allow the application code to directly access any table. You might have a table "People" containing names and other common *people* data, with tables "MemberData" and "AuthorData" containing more specific data. Create views "Members" and "Authors" and the apps don't even have to know some of the data is in a common table. Later in the life of the database when you want to add, drop or rename a column, or make just about any structural changes to the underlying schema, this will greatly reduce your maintenance effort.

Of course, using views like this can only be done on DBMSs that allow triggers on views, but all the good ones do.